# Cython compiler errors

Tags: python, c, cython

I'm on an older computer and i'm attempting to use Cython to speed up some python code I wrote, however I cannot get Cython to work with even the simplest of scripts.

Here is the python code i am attempting to run through Cython, and from my knowledge should work:

```
def hw():
    print "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hw()
```

And here is the output from my terminal:

```
C:\PyProjects\_cython>python hw.py
Hello World

C:\PyProjects\_cython>cython hw.py

C:\PyProjects\_cython>gcc hw.c
In file included from hw.c:4:
Python.h:8:22: error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
hw.c:457: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__Pyx_
PyInt_AsUnsignedLongLong'
hw.c:461: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__Pyx_
PyInt_AsLongLong'
hw.c:465: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__Pyx_
PyInt_AsSignedLongLong'
hw.c: In function '__Pyx_PyUnicode_Equals':
hw.c:826: error: 'Py_UNICODE' undeclared (first use in this function)
hw.c:826: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
hw.c:826: error: for each function it appears in.)
hw.c:826: error: expected ';' before 'ch1'
hw.c:827: error: expected ';' before 'ch2'
hw.c:828: error: 'ch1' undeclared (first use in this function)
hw.c:828: error: 'ch2' undeclared (first use in this function)
hw.c: At top level:
hw.c:1204: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__Pyx
_PyInt_AsUnsignedLongLong'
hw.c:1274: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__Pyx
_PyInt_AsLongLong'
hw.c:1344: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__Pyx
_PyInt_AsSignedLongLong'
hw.c: In function '__Pyx_InitStrings':
hw.c:1564: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
hw.c: In function '__Pyx_PyInt_AsSize_t':
hw.c:1669: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'val'
hw.c:1669: error: 'val' undeclared (first use in this function)
hw.c:1670: error: expected ')' before 'LONG_LONG'
hw.c:1672: error: expected ')' before 'LONG_LONG'
```

I am on windows 7 64bit using 32bit python 2.7

Comment: Your `gcc` command is missing include directories and other options.

Comment: To make Basile's comment more specific. Ensure Python.h is reachable as an include by gcc for a start.

Comment: Alright, I used "gcc hw.c -IC:\Python27\include" and here is the result: http://codepad.org/7uqvY7ui
It still fails and throws an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html#building-a-cython-module-using-distutils).  In my experience, the easiest way to do this is using `distutils` as it knows all the information necessary to pass along to the compiler (e.g. location of headers, important libraries, compiler options to create a suitable shared object, etc)  And, after all, writing a `setup.py` file isn't terribly difficult.  If you don't want to install the library, just do `python setup.py build` and copy the shared object into whatever directory you want (although you might need to dig a little in the `build` directory in order to find it).